# readHTMLTable collapsing span elements

Tags: html, xml, r

I am trying to fetch game data from this [site](http://scores.nbcsports.msnbc.com/cbk/teamstats.asp?team=1115&report=schedule) and using the XML package to do so:

```
library(XML)
url <- 'http://scores.nbcsports.msnbc.com/cbk/teamstats.asp?team=1115&report=schedule'
raw.schedule <- readHTMLTable(url, which=2)
```

The problem is that all of the `<span>` elements in the HTML date column are collapsing together.

```
R> raw.schedule$Date[1]
[1] "11/142:30 PM PT3:30 PM MT4:30 PM CT5:30 PM ET10:30 PM GMT6:30 PM åŒ—äº¬æ—¶é—´3:30 PM MST5:30 PM EST"
```

Ideally I would like to have just the date element by itself such as:

```
R> raw.schedule$Date[1]
    [1] "11/14"
```

I have tried rvest package but am having the same issue. Is it possible to read this table and keep the `<span>` elements separated, or just select the first element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a custom function to parse the cells of the table:

```
myFun <- function(x){
  if(length(y <- getNodeSet(x, "./span[@class=\"shsGameDate\"]")) > 0){
    # date column
     return(xmlValue(y[[1]]))
  }
  if(length(y <- getNodeSet(x, "./span[@class=\"shsTimezone shsETZone\"]")) > 0){
    # time column
    return(xmlValue(y[[1]]))
  }
  xmlValue(x, encoding = "UTF-8")
}
```

You can now call the `readHTMLTable` function using your custom function to parse the cells:

```
library(XML)
url <- 'http://scores.nbcsports.msnbc.com/cbk/teamstats.asp?team=1115&report=schedule'
raw.schedule <- readHTMLTable(url, which=2, elFun = myFun)

> head(raw.schedule)
   Date      Opponent       Time TV     Result
1 11/14     vs.  Yale 5:30 PM ET    W  88 - 85
2 11/18 vs.  La Salle 8:00 PM ET    L  58 - 60
3 11/22    at  Albany 7:00 PM ET    W  76 - 73
4 11/25 vs.  Hartford 7:00 PM ET    L  50 - 54
5 11/30  vs.  Vermont 1:00 PM ET    W  89 - 73
6  12/5     at  Siena 7:00 PM ET       Tickets
```